# MySQL: Using subquery returns null with error

Tags: mysql

Something about the following MySQL query is broken. I'm including the PHP for context:
  protected function scanAgainstUrlTargets(array $urlData) {
    global $wpdb;

```
$urlMatch = $wpdb->get_results("
  SELECT *
  FROM {$wpdb->prefix}delayedCoupons_targets t
  WHERE t.targetUrl = {$urlData['rawUrl']}
  AND t.displayThreshold < (
    select count(*)
    from {$wpdb->prefix}delayedCoupons_visits v
    where v.urlVisited = {$urlData['rawUrl']}
    as visitCount)
  AND visitCount < t.displayThreshold + t.offerCutoff
");

 return $urlMatch;
}
```

The error I see inline my debugger in $wpdb->last_error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
 version for the right syntax to use near '://localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/plugins.php?
plugin_status=all&paged=1&s
      AND ' at line 3
```

Here is the value for $wpdb->last_query:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM wp_delayedCoupons_targets t
  WHERE t.targetUrl = http://localhost/wptest2/wp- admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s
  AND t.displayThreshold < (
    select count(*)
    from wp_delayedCoupons_visits v
    where v.urlVisited = http://localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s
    as visitCount)
  AND visitCount < t.displayThreshold + t.offerCutoff
```

$urlData shows this in the debugger, confirming the variables are passing correctly:

```
rawUrl = http://localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s
urlRoot = http://localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/plugins.php
queryString = ?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s
```

I'm having a tough time with this one. If I had to guess, maybe something with how I alias the subquery to visitCount as that's new for me.
Does anyone see the issue?

Also Tried:

Running the query in CLI and using single quotes or backticks areound both URL strings. The Error shifts to point to the opening subquery parenthesis in both instances, like this:

```
owner@G700:/var/www/html/wptest2/wp-content/plugins/delayedCoupons$ 
SELECT * FROM wp_delayedCoupons_targets t WHERE t.targetUrl = 
'http://localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/plugins.php? 
plugin_status=all&paged=1&s' AND t.displayThreshold < ( select 
count(*) from wp_delayedCoupons_visits v where v.urlVisited = 
'http://localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/plugins.php? 
plugin_status=all&paged=1&s' as visitCount) AND visitCount < 
t.displayThreshold + t.offerCutoff

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

---

Updating to this query produces a new error:

```
$urlMatch = $wpdb->get_results("
  SELECT *, (select count(*) from wp_delayedCoupons_visits v where v.urlVisited = 'localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/plugins.php? plugin_status=all&paged=1&s' as visitCount)
  FROM {$wpdb->prefix}delayedCoupons_targets t
  WHERE t.targetUrl = {$urlData['rawUrl']}
  AND t.displayThreshold < visitCount
  AND visitCount < t.displayThreshold + t.offerCutoff
");

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as visitCount)
      FROM wp_delayedCoupons_targets t
      WHERE t.targetUrl = ' at line 1
```

Comment: put this subquery in main select (select 
count(*) from wp_delayedCoupons_visits v where v.urlVisited = 
'http://localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/plugins.php? 
plugin_status=all&paged=1&s' as visitCount) then use visitCount in Where clause

Comment: Thanks, there is a new error, something about the alias seems to be wrong. I have updated the original post

Comment: take as visitCount outside () brackets

Comment: try this `SELECT *, 
 (select count(*) from wp_delayedCoupons_visits v where v.urlVisited = 'localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/plugins.php? plugin_status=all&paged=1&s') as visitCount
  FROM {$wpdb->prefix}delayedCoupons_targets t
  WHERE t.targetUrl = {$urlData['rawUrl']}
  AND t.displayThreshold < visitCount
  AND visitCount < t.displayThreshold + t.offerCutoff`

Comment: Ok, I have done this but now the previous error is shown again: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '://localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s
      AND ' at line 3`

Comment: ok looks like some issue with the url string can you try the query with some test string like `demo` and check if query compiles. So repalce `://localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s` with `demo`

Comment: Ok, after I replaced the 2nd string, but not the 1st one, I received a new error. Looks like a persisting alias issue: `Unknown column 'visitCount' in 'where clause'`  || The query used was: `SELECT *, (select count(*) from wp_delayedCoupons_visits v where v.urlVisited = 'demoPosition1') as visitCount
      FROM {$wpdb->prefix}delayedCoupons_targets t
      WHERE t.targetUrl = 'stringPosition2'
      AND t.displayThreshold < visitCount
      AND visitCount < t.displayThreshold + t.offerCutoff`

Comment: Did you mean to write `SELECT *, as visitCount`  ? I changed it to the following but then got an error: `SELECT * as visitCount
      FROM {$wpdb->prefix}delayedCoupons_targets t
      WHERE t.targetUrl = 'stringPosition2'
        AND t.displayThreshold < (
          select count(*)
          from wp_delayedCoupons_visits v
          where v.urlVisited = 'demoPosition1')
        AND (
          select count(*)
          from wp_delayedCoupons_visits v
          where v.urlVisited = 'demoPosition1'
          ) < t.displayThreshold + t.offerCutoff`

Comment: Error message: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as visitCount
      FROM wp_delayedCoupons_targets t
      WHERE t.targetUrl = '' at line 1`

Comment: Sorry copy pasted wrong one try this `SELECT t.*
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}delayedCoupons_targets t 
WHERE t.targetUrl = 'stringPosition2' 
AND 
t.displayThreshold < (select count(*) from wp_delayedCoupons_visits v where v.urlVisited = 'demoPosition1') 
AND 
(select count(*) from wp_delayedCoupons_visits v where v.urlVisited = 'demoPosition1') < t.displayThreshold + t.offerCutoff`

Comment: Well done, it works now. Please post as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To use subquery single time use this:**

`SELECT t.*,visitData.count
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}delayedCoupons_targets t,
(select count(*) as count from wp_delayedCoupons_visits v where v.urlVisited = 'demoPosition1') as visitData
WHERE t.targetUrl = 'stringPosition2' 
AND 
t.displayThreshold < visitData.count
AND 
visitData.count < t.displayThreshold + t.offerCutoff`

**To use subquery in Where (This will be slow and not good):**

`SELECT t.* FROM {$wpdb->prefix}delayedCoupons_targets t 
WHERE t.targetUrl = 'stringPosition2' 
AND t.displayThreshold < (select count(*) from wp_delayedCoupons_visits v where v.urlVisited = 'demoPosition1') 
AND (select count(*) from wp_delayedCoupons_visits v where v.urlVisited = 'demoPosition1') < t.displayThreshold + t.offerCutoff`

Answer (score 0):

you have a `as visitCount` after the where clause in subquery could by you need  an alias for count(*) but you cant use alias in compare subquery so you should repeat the subquery code instead of alias

```
   $urlMatch = $wpdb->get_results("
      SELECT *
      FROM {$wpdb->prefix}delayedCoupons_targets t
      WHERE t.targetUrl = {$urlData['rawUrl']}
      AND t.displayThreshold < (
        select count(*)
        from {$wpdb->prefix}delayedCoupons_visits v
        where v.urlVisited = {$urlData['rawUrl']}
        )
      AND (
        select count(*)
        from {$wpdb->prefix}delayedCoupons_visits v
        where v.urlVisited = {$urlData['rawUrl']}
        ) < t.displayThreshold + t.offerCutoff
    ");
```

Comment: Thanks, I have made this update but there must be other issues as the error in the debugger and the cli error are both the same as in the original post

Comment: .. then you error depend of the content some vars .. try take a look at the related  content and at the effective code produceded after var substitutions ...

Comment: answer updated ..  you can't use alias  incomparing subquery

Comment: I tried your new query and the "last query" property shows your updated query. But error is still the same